# How to sort array in Python based on particular data set

Tags: python

I am using Python and have the following directories and files in an array list as shown below:

```
file_list = []
for file in file_list:
    print(file)
```

The output is shown below in no particular order.

```
Testcase/result.log
Testcase/system/system.log
Testcase/data/database.log
Testcase/mem/mem.log
Testcase/cashe/cashe.log
```

Now, I have another Python string called `target_str` that can have random values, for example `'mem'` or `'database'`. In this case, if the `target_str` matches with the entry of `file_list` contents, the order of the `file_list` array should be changed and the matched value should come first.

For example:

```
target_str = 'mem'

    Testcase/mem/mem.log   [Note: this entry moves at the first position since it matches the 'target_str']    
    Testcase/result.log
    Testcase/system/system.log
    Testcase/data/database.log
    Testcase/cashe/cashe.log
```

Wondering how to sort the `file_list` entry based on the value of `target_str`?

Comment: have you tried any code?if yes, do share

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the function `sorted()` and provide it a lambda key. In this case, we'll keep them the same order, but move the ones containing `target_str` to the top:

```
file_list = [
    'Testcase/result.log',
    'Testcase/system/system.log',
    'Testcase/data/database.log',
    'Testcase/mem/mem.log',
    'Testcase/cashe/cashe.log',
]
print(
    sorted(file_list, key=lambda f:[target_str not in f, file_list.index(f)])
)
# [
#    'Testcase/mem/mem.log', 
#    'Testcase/result.log', 
#    'Testcase/system/system.log', 
#    'Testcase/data/database.log', 
#    'Testcase/cashe/cashe.log'
# ]
```

If the `key` function for `sorted()` returns a list or tuple, then the elements take sort priority in that order. First, sort by `target_str not in f` (`False` sorts before `True`, so if the filename *does* contain the target string, it'll come first). Then, in case of a tie, sort by the index of the filename.

---

If you have a very large list of files, then you might want to sort `enumerate(file_list)` instead, to get the index of each file without having to call `.index()` every time. `.index()` is expensive.

Comment: Exactly what i am looking for:  Keep them the same order, but move the ones containing target_str to the top.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you just want to rearrange the paths including `target_dir` to the top. You could filter the paths which includes `target_dir` and combine with the rest

```
data = [
  'Testcase/result.log',
  'Testcase/system/system.log',
  'Testcase/data/database.log',
  'Testcase/mem/mem.log',
  'Testcase/cashe/cashe.log',
]

target_dir = 'mem'

target = [item for item in data if target_dir in item]
rest = [item for item in data if item not in target]

res = [*target, *rest]

print(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorting would not be a good idea here.
Instead use a [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).

```
file_list = ["Testcase/result.log",
"Testcase/system/system.log",
"Testcase/data/database.log",
"Testcase/mem/mem.log",
"Testcase/cashe/cashe.log"]
d  = {}
from collections import OrderedDict
keys = list(map(lambda x:x.split("/")[-1].strip(".log"), file_list))#I took the <text>.log  the text as the key 
d = OrderedDict(zip(keys,file_list))
text = "mem"
d.move_to_end(text, last=False)
print(d)
```

You can then use `list(d.values())` once you complete your process.